# How can I cleanly split and recombine Swift Publisher values? (using OpenCombine)

Tags: swift, combine

1. I have an upstream `Publisher` emitting values. For example, a stream of hex colors.
2. Separately I have an `Operator` backed by a `Publisher` that takes in those values and outputs some derived about them that is one-to-one in the long-term, but requires information about the value before or after. For example, returning the difference between each hex color and the color before it. **I can't modify this.**
3. I would like a simple way to return the two values together. E.g. a tuple `(color, differenceToPreviousColor)`
4. I am using OpenCombine for backwards compatibility and it might be missing some operators. For example, it doesn't have `zip` (if that's what I would even need)

Pseudocode:

```swift
// Can't mess with this. Basically just returns the consecutive differences
extension Publisher {
    func colorDiff<E>() -> AnyPublisher<Color, E> where Color == Output, E == Failure {
        return self
          .map({ ($0, $0) })
          .scan((Color.black(), Color.black()), {
            let (_, prev) = $0
            let (curr, _) = $1
            return (prev, curr)
          })
          .map({
            let (prev, curr) = $0
            return curr - prev
          })
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

let colorPublisher = ... // emits #333333; #444444; ...
```

What's the simplest way to do something like the below with OpenCombine (without using zip)?

```swift
let _ = zip(colorPublisher, colorPublisher.colorDiff()).sink { (e) in } receiveValue: { (tuple) in
      debugPrint(tuple.description) // (#333333, #333333); (#444444, #111111); ...
    }
```

Comment: I switched from OpenCombine to [CombineX](https://github.com/cx-org/CombineX) because CombineX is a more complete re-implementation of Combine. CombineX includes `zip`.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the tip!!

Comment: Yeah hadn’t heard about that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "hacky" workaround, is via `handleEvents` (OpenCombine has this), which allows you to intercept different events that occur during the lifetime of the publisher.

```swift
// just a placeholder, giving an initial value to avoid the need for
// an optional, anyway this value will be overwritten by the first
// published value
var currentColor = Color.black()

_ = colorPublisher
    // intercept the published value, stored it into a local variable
    .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { currentColor = $0 })
    .colorDiff()
    // now combine the latest received color and the diff, into a tuple
    .map { (currentColor, $0) }
    .sink(receiveValue: { debugPrint($0) })
```

Or, if you want to capture the last two items (for 3,4... items you can extend the tuple, or use an array):

```swift
var latestColors = (secondLast: Color.black(), last: Color.black())
_ = colorPublisher
    .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { latestColors = (latestColors.last, $0) })
    .colorDiff()
    .map { (latestColors.last, latestColors.secondLast, $0) }
    .sink(receiveValue: { debugPrint($0) })
```

Regarding the availability of the `zip` operator, OpenCombine has a PR for this - https://github.com/OpenCombine/OpenCombine/pull/109, however the PR is not yet mergeable, but you can use that branch if you want to check out the operator implementation.

Comment: Thanks! This works well if colorDiff uses the item before. Unfortunately, if I needed the item after, the associations would be off-by-one (currentColor would be refer to the newest item, but colorDiff() is giving info about the second latest item). My real case is doing some signal processing that requires a lag like that. E.g. Peak detection requires knowing that the preceding and following data points are smaller than this one. This is probably just a case of adding a delay aspect to the currentColor variable. Still messy, but maybe the best I got if I were using OpenCombine. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamA if you are sure that the new publisher does this, then you can store the last two values into a tuple, and pass along the one before last element. I've updated the answer to include a sample code for this.

Comment: Thanks. Definitely ugly, but seems like the right answer to a funky question. Could still get tripped up with any async in colorDiff, but in my case that's not an issue (I don't think...)

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you need `zip` for this. If you are generating colors to start with, capture each color and keep passing it down the pipeline *along with* the color diff that you generate from it.

This is a crude analog using numbers, but it shows you what I mean:

```
var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
let data = Array(1...100).shuffled()
struct Info {
    let this: Int
    let diff: Int?
    let first: Bool
}
data.publisher
    .scan (Info(this: 0, diff: 0, first: true)) { info, this in
        Info(this: this, diff: info.first ? nil : this - info.this, first: false)
    }
    .map {($0.this, $0.diff)}
    .sink { print($0) }
    .store(in:&storage)
```

Sample output:

```
(80, nil)
(47, Optional(-33))
(35, Optional(-12))
...
```

We end up with pairs: this number, along its difference from the previous number (couched as an Optional because the very first number has no previous number to diff with, and we need a way of saying that). But those are exactly the pairs that zip would have given you in your imaginary scenario, no?

What I'm trying to say is that the whole notion of "split and recombine" is repugnant to the way Combine works. If some value that appears early in the pipeline will be needed for a later stage of the pipeline, keep passing it on down through the intermediate stages, along with whatever else the intermediate stages are processing. Tuples, or carrier structs like my Info, are crucial for this kind of work.

You *can* do a "split and recombine", but I cannot imagine how it could work except by using `zip`. Here's my example, rewritten to use that approach. It's a pain to write it out using Combine, and you'll notice that I've used `makeConnectable` and `connect` because otherwise all the values in my example spill down one pathway (because my example is not actually asynchronous):

```
    let data = Array(1...100).shuffled()
    struct Info {
        let prev: Int
        let diff: Int?
        let first: Bool
    }
    let pub = data.publisher.share().makeConnectable()
    let path1 = pub
    let path2 = pub
        .scan(Info(prev: 0, diff: nil, first: true)) {
            Info(prev:$1, diff: $0.first ? nil : $1 - $0.prev, first: false)
        }
        .map {$0.diff}
    path1
        .zip(path2)
        .sink {print($0)}
        .store(in: &storage)
    _ = pub.connect()
```

Sample output:

```
(39, nil)
(56, Optional(17))
(22, Optional(-34))
...
```

Comment: This violates the "cannot change colorDiff" requirement. But if "the whole notion of "split and recombine" is repugnant to the way Combine works." then fair enough. Sounds like your answer is that Combine's Publishers can't be combined well in this way? I'd have to pull the core logic out of colorDiff (or whatever I'm doing) and only reuse that.

Comment: Like the downside to this is that intermediate stages now need to know and care about this outside value that a later stage will need, but they don't need themselves. Is that really the best we can do?

Comment: The reason I added the "requires the item before" requirement is because that makes it harder to share the underlying logic without a Publisher. The underlying logic would still need to know about context that the Publisher would have. But maybe there is a better way to share that kind of logic? Sequence something?

Comment: OK I'll add a split-and-recombine solution, but it does require `zip`!